# Limits on stable charged particles

Tags: particle-physics, large-hadron-collider

Are there generic model-independent limits on massive stable charged particles (say 10-500GeV)? I mean SU(2)/color singlets with just a hypercharge.

For example the LEP search (CERN-EP/99-075) was only for masses greater than 45GeV. Recent LHC searches seem to make assumptions about lifetimes, R-Hadron formation etc. Are there generic limits from precision electroweak? References would be appreciated.